# Installed RVM, rvm commands do not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I just went through the RVM install.

I did this command:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

and everything ran fine.  Then in my user home directory, in .bash_profile I added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Then I started a new shell just to be sure.  And then I tried

```
rvm
```

and got the error that

```
No command 'rvm' found
```

Any ideas why that might happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see the "Troubleshooting your Install" section on [this](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) page.

It mentions that you need to remove `return` from your .bashrc. I often forget to do this on a fresh ubuntu install.

The example they give for ubuntu is to change this:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
# Some code here... e.g.
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

to this:

```
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then
  # Some code here... e.g.
  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
fi
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, I made that change.  Was it supposed to make the rvn command do something? What is a good test to see if it worked?

Answer (score 8):

maybe it is because .bash_profile only runs on login, if you run a new shell it only executes .bashrc

You could test using

```
> bash -l
```

Comment: the bash -l command returned nothing.  What would that mean? :)  Thanks!

Comment: it is not supposed to return anything it runs a new bash shell but runs the .bash_profile which means rvm will be setup in that new shell.