# RVM Command Not Working After Gem Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I installed RVM with `sudo rvm install` and now I'm trying to call `rvm use 1.9.3` before I start a Rails project but I'm getting this error from the command line: `-bash: rvm: command not found`

Anybody have an idea what my problem is?

And when I try `rvm -v` I get the same error message.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866064/rvm-command-not-working-after-gem-install#15866064) help?

Answer (score 1):

Found the error.

**Bash profiles only run at login:**
[Installed RVM, rvm commands do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750981/installed-rvm-rvm-commands-do-not-work?rq=1)

If you experience this error simply try opening a new tab in terminal.

Comment: you can also $source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Answer (score 0):

try installing rvm as

curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable